# Confusion regarding $\models \forall x A \equiv \forall y A[y/x]$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have some confusion regarding the following statement given in Jean H. Gallier's book "Logic for Computer Science". It says,

> For every formula $A$ $$\models \forall x A \equiv \forall y A[y/x]$$

Now if I take $A = \forall y \Phi(x,y)$, then $A[y/x] = \Phi(y,y)$. Hence using above statement I have 
$$\models \forall x \forall y \Phi(x,y) \equiv \forall y \forall y \Phi(y,y)$$
Which is just 
$$\models \forall x \forall y \Phi(x,y) \equiv \forall y \Phi(y,y)$$
And this statement is definitely wrong. Is this because I am using a bounded variable to substitute a free variable ?
My end goal was to actually prove the following,
$$\forall x \forall y \Phi(x,y) \rightarrow \forall y \Phi(y,y) $$
How do I prove this ?

---

Here is the proof from tree proof generator 
https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%80x%E2%88%80yF(x,y)%E2%86%92%E2%88%80yF(y,y)

---

But a better proof will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A = ∀yΦ(x,y)$ , then $A[y/x]=A$ because $y$ is **not** free for $x$ in $A$.

The proof must be:

1) $∀x∀yΦ(x,y)$,

2) $∀yΦ(z,y)$ by [Universal Instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation),

3) $Φ(z,z)$ by UI,

and finally:

> $∀yΦ(y,y)$ by [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

But the last formula is not equivalent to the first one: consider $\forall y (y \le y)$, which is true in $\mathbb N$, and $\forall x \forall y (x \le y)$, which is not.

---

Regarding the title: 1) $\forall x A$, 2) $A[y/x]$, if $y$ is free for $x$ in $A$, 3) $\forall y A[y/x]$.

Comment: UI and UG stand for ?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer, I would like to ask about an extension too, $\forall X \Phi(X) \rightarrow \forall(X)\Phi(X')$, where $X' \in X^{|X|}$, and $X$ is the set of variables. You have already answered my previous question, and now I have an idea how I can prove all the cases of the statement I mentioned now, but what will be the most compact argument.

Comment: @SagarM - Not clear... The set of variables ? Usually, the variables of FOL language are infinite many.

Comment: I am sorry I should have clarified, $\Phi(X)$ is a function free, quantifier-free formula. $X = \{x_1,x_2, ... x_n\}$. $\forall X$ refers to universal quantification of all variables in $X$, $X^{|X|}$ refers to the cartesian product of $X$ with itself $n$ times. for example for $X=(x,y)$, $X^{|X|} = \{ (x,y),(x,x),(y,y),(y,x) \} $

Comment: @SagarM - Are you meaning simultaneous substitution  ? $\forall x_1 \ldots x_n \Phi \equiv \forall y_1 \ldots y_n \Phi [y_1/x_1, \ldots y_n/x_n]$ ?

Comment: I am sorry my First Order logic is not the best. But the statement you mentioned requires $y_i$ to be free for $x_i$ which is not the case that I mentioned. So for $\forall x \forall y f(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y f(y,y )$, also, $\forall x \forall y f(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y f(x,x )$, also $\forall x \forall y f(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y f(y,x )$ also $\forall x \forall y f(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y f(x,y )$. I want to do this for any finite number of variables. for $\forall_{x,y,x}f(x,y,z)$ there will be 27 such cases. for $(x,y)$ there are 4

Comment: Hi, I will post this as a separate question so that it's clear